# Обновить в поле в базе данных на одно меньшее от имеющегося

Tags: mysql

Например у меня в поле yellow сейчас хранится число 7.

Как одним sql - запросом сделать 6 ?

Сейчас я делаю, то что сперва вызываю селект, достаю оттуда число плюсую, только затем деаю обновление.

```
UPDATE tracker_users SET `yellow` = '?' WHERE `id` = '$id_user'
```

Как это сделать без лишних действий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `yellow`=`yellow`-1 WHERE `id`="1"
```